# Is there a language in which `print, "hello, world!"` is a valid Hello World program?

Tags: identification

My Code Jam T-shirt has the following snippet of code on the front.

```
print, "hello, world!"
```

Here is an image of it (taken from the Hash Code Twitter, not my T-shirt):

[image]

This is not a correct Hello World program in any language that I know. It is almost Python 2, but not quite. Apparently it runs in Javascript, but it doesn't give any output. I have asked several people, and none of them know.

Is there any programming language in which this is a valid Hello, world program?

Comment: Print "Hello world" works in BASIC, but it lacks the comma.

Comment: Indeed, then it also works in Python 2 -- it's the comma that's weird.

Comment: `AutoHotKey` scripts accept (optional) comma after commands, but I think it has no `print` command

Comment: It at least _works_ in Basic, though, rather than throwing a parse error. (the comma moves the next part to the next "zone", e.g. it's basically -heyo- tabulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be Basic, which uses the comma as a "zone" delimiter. So it basically (hah) effects a 15 space indent before "hello world!".

See http://www.dartmouth.edu/basicfifty/commands.html, "PRINT Statements".

Although of course, it could *also* be something else entirely =D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like early algol or similar language, comma after print indicates omitted first parameter (which was device name or punch device id usually). Not all implementations allowed to omit it, but such omission was inherited by 80s-90s interpreter languages.

Algol 60 didn't had standard I/O, but some versions had output in form of `PRINT <device>, <some tags>, <data>`

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind? In [ALGOL 68 on TIO](https://tio.run/##S8xJz88xs0j//7@gKDOvREdBKSM1JydfR6E8vygnRen/fwA) it doesn't work.

Comment: @MeesdeVries ALGOL60, some dialect (often individual computer model had own one), it misses begin \end and something at end of line though, 68 used printf  and C-like syntax :P